# Access nth argument after use of \SplitArgument in \NewDocumentCommand?

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

It is a bit artificial, but assume the following as context:

First, I want to add labels for tables as `tab:label`, for figures as `fig:label` and so on.
Second, I want to create some commands to include figures, tables, etc.

```
%{caption; label} %table def %table content
\NewDocumentCommand{\includetable}{> { \SplitArgument { 1 } { ; } } m m m}{
  \begin{table}[htb!]
    \captionlabel#1 % the Question is about this line; how do I pass the prefix?
    \begin{tabular}{#2}
        #3
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
}
```

And I have a command that inserts a caption and a label, which looks as follows:

```
%caption %label prefix %label
\NewDocumentCommand{\captionlabel}{m O{} m}{
    \caption{#1}\label{#2#3} 
}
```

The question is if it is somehow possible to call `\captionlabel` from `\includetable` and pass the `tab:` prefix (something like `\captionlabel {#1.1}[tab:]{#1.2}`).

I know that I could remove the optional argument in `\captionlabel` and always call `\includetable` with `tab:label`, or I could switch the order of the arguments of `\captionlabel` to `{O{} m m}` or `{m m O{}}`, or inline the command. It is basically just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\NewDocumentCommand` is for defining user-facing commands, but things are easier and cleaner in `expl3` when you define a code-level API on which the user-level commands are based. One of the reasons is that it is very easy to generate variants of code-level functions with `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`, whereas commands defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` don't support this. Here are two ways to solve your problem that keep the interface of your `\captionlabel` command intact.

## First solution

This solution uses a code-level function `\fabian_insert_caption_and_label:nnn` where the two arguments provided via `\SplitArgument` occupy adjacent positions (namely, poistions 2 and 3):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \fabian_insert_caption_and_label:nnn #1#2#3
  { \caption {#2} \label {#1#3} }

\NewDocumentCommand { \includetable } { > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { ; } } m m m }
  {
    \begin{table}[htb!]
    \centering
    \fabian_insert_caption_and_label:nnn { tab: } #1

    \begin{tabular}{#2}
      #3
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  }

% Useless here, but maybe you want it for other code of yours.
\NewDocumentCommand { \captionlabel } { m O{} m }
  {
    \fabian_insert_caption_and_label:nnn {#2} {#1} {#3}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \includetable{Caption text; the label}{ll}{This & is\\ a & table}

  See table~\ref{tab:the label} on page~\pageref{tab:the label}.
\end{document}
```

## Second solution

This solution uses a code-level function `\fabian_insert_caption_and_label:nnn` different from the one in the first solution: it accepts the arguments in the same order as your `\captionlabel`. In order to manage the two “non-adjacent arguments”, we pass them manually after splitting ourselves the first argument of `\includetable`. Note that you could, and probably should create a code-level function corresponding to this `\includetable`. This way, reusing the code is easier (I did not do it in order not to mix all issues, but it is just a simple wrapper that I am talking about: see below).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \fabian_insert_caption_and_label:nnn #1#2#3
  { \caption {#1} \label {#2#3} }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fabian_insert_caption_and_label:nnn { xnx }

\seq_new:N \l_fabian_tmp_seq

\NewDocumentCommand { \includetable } { m m m }
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_fabian_tmp_seq { ; } {#1}

    \begin{table}[htb!]
    \centering
    \fabian_insert_caption_and_label:xnx
      { \seq_item:Nn \l_fabian_tmp_seq { 1 } }
      { tab: }
      { \seq_item:Nn \l_fabian_tmp_seq { 2 } }

    \begin{tabular}{#2}
      #3
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \captionlabel } { m O{} m }
  {
    \fabian_insert_caption_and_label:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \includetable{Caption text; the label}{ll}{This & is\\ a & table}

  See table~\ref{tab:the label} on page~\pageref{tab:the label}.
\end{document}
```

If speed is a concern, I would use `\seq_pop:NN` twice instead of `\seq_item:Nn` twice, because the latter iterates over the whole sequence every time, whereas `\seq_pop:NN` just stores and removes the first item, which is very fast (the result is `\q_no_value` when there is no item to pop anymore).

## Suggested wrapper for `\includetable`

When I said above that I would suggest that you add a simple code-level function corresponding to your `\includetable`, what I meant was simply something like that:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \fabian_include_table:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_fabian_tmp_seq { ; } {#1}

    \begin{table}[htb!]
    \centering
    \fabian_insert_caption_and_label:xnx
      { \seq_item:Nn \l_fabian_tmp_seq { 1 } }
      { tab: }
      { \seq_item:Nn \l_fabian_tmp_seq { 2 } }

    \begin{tabular}{#2}
      #3
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \includetable } { m m m }
  {
    \fabian_include_table:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
  }
```

This way, you can very easily define variants of `\fabian_include_table:nnn` using `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`. You can also change its interface if needed (assuming it is not part of a public package) without changing the interface of the user-level command `\includetable`.

## Output of both examples

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I can't recommend such a syntax. Just for academic interest, here's how you can do:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\includetable}{> { \SplitArgument { 2 } { ; } } m m m}{%
  \begin{table}[htb!]
    \centering
    \addcaptionlabel#1
    \begin{tabular}{#2}
        #3
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\captionlabel}{m O{} m}{%
  \caption{#1}\label{#2#3} 
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addcaptionlabel}{mmm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
    \captionlabel{#1}{#2}%
  }{%
    \captionlabel{#1}[#2]{#3}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\ref{DEF} and \ref{prefixDEF}

\includetable{ABC;DEF}{cc}{11 & 22 \\ 333 & 4}

\includetable{ABC;prefix;DEF}{cc}{11 & 22 \\ 333 & 4}

\end{document}
```

[image]